# AngularJS injection Error - Unknown provider: modalMessagesProvider <- modalMessages

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a service opening an angular-ui-bootstrap modal with a component controller.
But my controller can't get access to the parameter i am passing on (modalMessages, i just want to print it).
The error is: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: modalMessagesProvider <- modalMessages

Can anyone help?

Service:

```
angular.module('app').service('AlertService', function ($uibModal) {
    this.showModal = function (modalMessages) {
        return $uibModal.open({
            component: "modalComponent",
            resolve: {
                modalMessages: function () {
                    return modalMessages;
                }
            }
        }).result;
    }
});
```

Component Controller:

```
'use strict';

const Modal = {
    templateUrl: 'views/modals/modalAlert.html',
    controller: ['modalMessages', ModalCtrl],
    controllerAs: '$ctrl',
    bindings: {
        modalMessages: "<",
    }
}


angular.module('app').component('modalComponent', Modal);

function ModalCtrl() {

    this.modalMessages = modalMessages;
    console.log(this.modalMessages);
}
```

Comment: Where is the service `modalMessages` which you are using inside `AlertService` ?

Comment: The Service is called like this: `AlertService.showModal({
    header: 'header',
    information: 'info'
   });`

Comment: I tried to inject modalMessages to the controller, so it has to be `function ModalCtrl(modalMessages)`

Comment: Can you check if you have `.service('modalMessages',`anywhere defined ?

Comment: I don't, because it shouldn't be a service, it should be a parameter given from the service to the component

Comment: would you mind creating a  demo example on plunkr.com ? I'll fix that code for you.

Comment: [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/tWvRLignt5OKfYlnn40l?p=preview) thx :)

Comment: let me know if my answer worked for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ea3Q2WD75L9xkcWxyVU9?p=preview)

Notice the changes I have done in:

```
(function(){
  const Modal = {
    templateUrl: 'modalAlert.html',
    controller:  ModalCtrl,
    bindings: {
      resolve: "<"
    }
};

angular.module('app').component('modalComponent', Modal);

function ModalCtrl() {
  var $ctrl = this;
  $ctrl.$onInit = function() {
    $ctrl.modalMessages = $ctrl.resolve.modalMessages;
  }
}

})()
```

you need to use `resolve` with `bindings` to access the passed paramaeter

Comment: I did, but: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: @Isabel ahhh.. true